# Aggregate not returning all calculations

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2,1, 2, 3, 2, 2),
       c(10, 10, 10,8,1, NA,8, NA, 6, NA, 9, 10, 8, 5, 8))
names(test) <- c("Group", "Q1")
```

I would like to apply the following function.

```
nps.exc <- function(x){
  exc <- subset(x, x<11)
  result <- data.frame("Detractors" = integer(0),
         "Passives" = integer(0), "Promoters" = integer(0))
  result[1,1] <- (length(which(exc < 7)))/length(exc)
  result[1,2] <- (length(which(exc == 7| exc == 8)))/length(exc)
  result[1,3] <- (length(which(exc == 9| exc == 10)))/length(exc)
  result
}
```

When I run the function on the entire dataset I get the three results (Detractors/Passives/Promoters):

```
nps.exc(test$Q1)
```

However, I would like it to be disaggregated by group (column 1). When I use aggregate I somehow lose the three separate results:

```
aggregate(Q1 ~ Group, test, nps.exc)
```

Total newbie here, what am I missing?

Comment: Try by changing the last line with `do.call(rbind, result)}` in `nps.exc`

Comment: @akrun - Thanks but it still doesn't work. Oddly enough, if I just run aggregate I see all three values in the console (group, detractors, passives, promoters). If I try to save aggregate (df1 <- aggregate...) it only returns a two column dataframe (Group, Detractors). If I run str(aggregate...) it also tells me it's only 2 columns wide.

Comment: I don't get any errors and I am getting 3 columns of value output

Comment: Even when you save to a variable? I get the 3 columns when I run the command but not when I try to save the result somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: It is because the result is stored as a `matrix` in a single column.  We can convert it to regular `data.frame` using  `res <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(Q1 ~ Group, test, nps.exc))` and `str(res)#
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:`

Comment: Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by changing the last line of 'nps.exc' to `do.call(rbind, result)`

```
 nps.exc <- function(x){
  exc <- subset(x, x<11)
 result <- data.frame("Detractors" = integer(0),
     "Passives" = integer(0), "Promoters" = integer(0))
 result[1,1] <- (length(which(exc < 7)))/length(exc)
 result[1,2] <- (length(which(exc == 7| exc == 8)))/length(exc)
 result[1,3] <- (length(which(exc == 9| exc == 10)))/length(exc)
 do.call(rbind, result)
 }
```

and use that in the `aggregate`

```
 res <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(Q1 ~ Group, test, nps.exc))
 str(res)
 #'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ Group: num  1 2 3
 #$ Q1.1 : num  0 0.375 0
 #$ Q1.2 : num  0 0.375 0.5
 #$ Q1.3 : num  1 0.25 0.5
```

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the insight. I didn't actually looked inside the code carefully.

Comment: @Frank Could you post as a new solution with all the improvements (possibly with `data.table`)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a natural place to use `table`, which excludes `NA`s by default; and `prop.table`, which converts a table from counts to proportions:

```
nps.exc <- function(x){
    xf <- factor(findInterval(x,c(7,9,11)),levels=c("0","1","2"))
    setNames(prop.table(table(xf)),c("Detractors","Passives","Promoters"))
}

aggregate(Q1 ~ Group, test, nps.exc)
#   Group Q1.Detractors Q1.Passives Q1.Promoters
# 1     1         0.000       0.000        1.000
# 2     2         0.375       0.375        0.250
# 3     3         0.000       0.500        0.500
```

*How it works:*

- `findInterval` maps `x` to the intervals based on the cut points `c(7,9,11)`, with `0` for anything below the first cut point.
- The `factor` part ensures that the three cases (< 7, 7-8, 9-10) are all considered, even if they don't show up in `x`; and that the fourth case (11+) is mapped to `NA`.

---

*Efficiency.* It would be more efficient to define `xf` for all of `Q1` instead of separately per `Group`:

```
nps.exc.g <- function(x,g){
    xf         <- factor(findInterval(x,c(7,9,11)),levels=c("0","1","2"))
    levels(xf) <- c("Detractors","Passives","Promoters")
    prop.table(table(g,xf),1)
}

with(test,nps.exc.g(Q1,Group))
#    xf
# g   Detractors Passives Promoters
#   1      0.000    0.000     1.000
#   2      0.375    0.375     0.250
#   3      0.000    0.500     0.500
```

The downside here is that the result is a `table`-class object, which is a pain.

Comment: This is very elegant.